# std::erase_if delete an extra elements on std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++20

I use `std::erase_if` to erase half the elements from containers using a captured counter as follows. C++20 compiled with `gcc10`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<int> container(10);
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
        std::erase_if(container, [i = 0u](auto&&...) mutable { return i++ % 2 == 0; });
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        std::map<int, int> container;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            container.emplace(i, i);
        }
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
        std::erase_if(container, [i = 0u](auto&&...) mutable { return i++ % 2 == 0; });
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> container;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            container.emplace(i, i);
        }
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
        std::erase_if(container, [i = 0u](auto&&...) mutable { return i++ % 2 == 0; });
        std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is unexpected. For vector, an extra element is removed:

```
10
4

10
5

10
5
```

I print out the result and it seems like `vector[1]` is the unexpectedly removed element

Granted that this is not usually a normal usage for erase_if but I'm still curious why it happens only for vector but not for the other map. I'd guess it has something to do with the iterator type shenanigan. Appreciate if someone could give a detailed explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterator type shenanigans"?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in g++. It works in the trunk version. [working](https://godbolt.org/z/osPdKKnPM) vs. [buggy](https://godbolt.org/z/jzdv58x84) and it works in clang++

Comment: Hmm. The same "bug" happens in MSVC (VS 2019).

Comment: It seems to only happen if you capture by copy (like in this case). If you capture a by reference or if you add a `static unsigned i = 0;` to the lambda, it works. Very odd that it behaves different when used in different algorithms. I'm guessing gcc made a copy of the lambda and uses that one time in `std::erase_if(vector)` @AdrianMole Yeah, I got the same in VS2022

Comment: "algorithms that take function objects as arguments can copy those function objects freely". See [this note](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#note-2) in the standard.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, but if it makes two copies of the original and uses both, the stateful lambda will be starting at 0 twice (which is what can be observed). That can't be ok.

Comment: Mutable lambda does not satisfy [`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable), which means that the same input may produce *different* results. I seriously suspect that this is UB when using it as a predicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`remove_if` takes a Predicate. And the [standard library requires that a Predicate type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/algorithms.requirements#7):

> Given a glvalue `u` of type (possibly const) `T` that designates the same object as `*first`, `pred(u)` shall be a valid expression that is equal to `pred(*first)`.

Your predicate changes its internal state. As such, calling it twice with the same element will yield different results. That means it does not fulfill the requirements of Predicate.

And therefore, undefined behavior ensues.

Comment: Ouch, that's a tough pill to swallow. This means that even if one captures `i` by reference may it yield different results for the same element - so even if the Predicate doesn't change it's internal state in that case, it would result in UB?

Comment: capture by ref does not mean mutable

Comment: @Kobi No it does not, which is exactly my point. It's not that it's mutable, changing it's internal state, that makes it have UB. It's that it's not necessarily giving the same result for the same element (if supplied to it more than once) that makes it have UB.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see your point and I understand it. Re-reading and refreshing my mem, maybe the issue is where you make a copy of the lambda. With ref, it would not matter. It's immutable lambda and the ref is copied though it is pointing/referring to the thing. With mutable lambda when making a copy, the members are different now. this is probably the violation. Someone commented that with ref it does not happening. But anyway, I think the issue is mutable is not satisfying some prereqs.